# How can i add css support in HTML to PDF using IText in Android?

Tags: java, android, itext, html-to-pdf

I have application to create PDF from html content. I am generating invoice from HTML template and create pdf from HTML String content.

I am using itext itext-pdf-5.5.9.jar and xmlworker-5.5.9.jar for parsing and genrating html.

here is my source code to generate HTML to PDF.

```
             String path=saveHTML(finalStrInvoice);
            String csspath=saveStyle();
            String cssSource=AppUtils.loadHtml(PDFPreview.this,"html/mystyle.css");
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = null;
            Log.d("tag","CSS:"+cssSource);
            try {
                writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
                document.open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                        new FileInputStream(path),new FileInputStream(csspath));
                document.close();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

---

```
private String saveHTML(String strInvoice) {
    File myFile = null;
    try {
         myFile= new File(dirPath,"invoice.html");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(strInvoice);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return myFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

PDF is generate successfully but CSS style is not apply in PDF.
Please help me.

```
            .invoice-box{
                max-width:800px;
                margin:auto;
                padding:30px;
                /* border:1px solid #eee;
                 box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);  */
                font-size:16px;
                line-height:24px;
                font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                color:#555;
            }

        .invoice-box table{
            width:100%;
            line-height:inherit;
            text-align:center;
            border-color:#eee;

        }
        td.invoci-parent{
            text-align:left !important;
        }
        .invoice-box table td{
            padding:5px;
            vertical-align:top;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2){
            text-align:right;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.top table td{
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title{
            font-size:45px;
            line-height:45px;
            color:#333;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.information table td{
            padding-bottom:40px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.heading td{
            background:#eee;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:left;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.details td{
            padding-bottom:20px;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.item td{
            border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
            text-align:left;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.item.last td{
            border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
            text-align:left;
        }

        .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2){
            border-top:2px solid #eee;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .sub-total td{
            text-align:right;
            border-top:1px solid #eee;
        }
        .invoice-total{
            text-align:right;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .invoice-box table tr.top table td{
                width:100%;
                display:block;
                text-align:center;
            }

            .invoice-box table tr.information table td{
                width:100%;
                display:block;
                text-align:center;
            }
        }
```

here is my css style

here is my html file.

Comment: Several people have claimed that "CSS doesn't work", but this was contradicted in answers to questions such as [Why doesn't CSS and RowSpan work?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-doesnt-css-and-rowspan-work), [How to add external CSS while generating PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-external-css-while-generating-pdf) and so on. It's true that *some CSS functionality* isn't supported in iText 5. That functionality is added to the iText 7 and pdfHTML: [Converting HTML to PDF with pdfHTML](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml)

Comment: Bottom line: if you want an answer, show us the CSS that is not applied. Then we can tell you if it's supported for iText 5 and XML Worker or not. If it's not supported, then you are out of luck, because further development to iText 5 and XML Worker has stopped. All new development will be done on iText 7 and pdfHTML.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : please check my css

Comment: Stuff like `:nth-child` and `@media` isn't supported in iText 5 + XML Worker; support for those things is only available in iText 7 + pdfHTML. See [Creating reports using pdfHTML](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml) for an example of `nth-child` and [Generating PDF based on Media Queries](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-3-generating-pdf-based-media-queries) for `@media` examples.

Comment: I have find i7 pdfhtml jar. but not found. Please share link to download pdfhtml library.

Comment: You can get a trial version here: [get the trial license](http://pages.itextpdf.com/iText-7-Free-Trial-Landing-Page-1.html).

Comment: I want to use itext5 and i have remove :nth-child and @media. but still css not apply to pdf.

Comment: Most of the CSS mentioned in your question works fine in the examples I have, so I can't help you any further. I can only fix problems I can reproduce. I can't fix problems that don't exist when I run an example. Furthermore, I don't want to spend much more time on iText 5, so you'll have to hope that you can find someone else who still wants to invest in *free* iText 5 support (of course: there is still *paid* support for iText 5).

Comment: Can you please give working sample code of html to pdf with css of itext5.?

Comment: I can give you plenty: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5

Comment: If you want a specific one, take a look at [ParseHtmlTable6](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables#973-parsehtmltable6.java) where we convert [paragj.html](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/html-tables#977-paragj.html) to [html_table_6.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/xmlworker/cmp_html_table_6.pdf). Are you claiming that the CSS doesn't work in this example?

Comment: No i am telling that in my html my css not working. same html is wokring in webview but when i generate pdf from html string it is not properly formated.

Comment: And I am telling you that I can give you examples of HTML files with CSS that *does* work when you convert that HTML+CSS to PDF, but I am not going to do any effort to try to reconstruct your HTML (which you don't share), nor will I write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (which you should have done) in an attempt to reproduce the problem (I can't reproduce it). See bullet 1 of the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please stop wasting my time. If you want help, write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or pay someone to help you.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for help